# How to fill missing value with different ways in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-mining

I have a dataset that has a number of numerical variables and a number of ordinal numeric variables. to fill missing value  I want to  use mean for numerical variables and use the median for the ordinal numeric variables. With the following code, each of them is created separately and is not collected in a database.

```
df = [['age', 'score'],
 [10,1],
 [20,""],
 ["",0],
 [40,1],
 [50,0],
 ["",3],
 [70,1],
 [80,""],
 [90,0],
[100,1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:])
df.columns = data[0]

df = df[['age']].fillna(df.mean())
df = df[['score']].fillna(df.median())
```

Comment: Is there a question here? Cause what you've written is an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace empty strings to missing values and then replace mising values per columns:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
df['age'] = df['age'].fillna(df['age'].mean())
df['score'] = df['score'].fillna(df['score'].median())

print (df)
     age  score
0   10.0    1.0
1   20.0    1.0
2   57.5    0.0
3   40.0    1.0
4   50.0    0.0
5   57.5    3.0
6   70.0    1.0
7   80.0    1.0
8   90.0    0.0
9  100.0    1.0
```

You can also use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) for `Series` of aggregate values and pass to [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)

print (df.agg({'age':'mean', 'score':'median'}))
age      57.5
score     1.0
dtype: float64

df = df.fillna(df.agg({'age':'mean', 'score':'median'}))
print (df)
     age  score
0   10.0    1.0
1   20.0    1.0
2   57.5    0.0
3   40.0    1.0
4   50.0    0.0
5   57.5    3.0
6   70.0    1.0
7   80.0    1.0
8   90.0    0.0
9  100.0    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) accepts dict with keys being column names, so you might do:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['age', 'score'],
 [10,1],
 [20,None],
 [None,0],
 [40,1],
 [50,0],
 [None,3],
 [70,1],
 [80,None],
 [90,0],
[100,1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

df = df.fillna({'age':df['age'].mean(),'score':df['score'].median()})
print(df)
```

output

```
     age  score
0   10.0    1.0
1   20.0    1.0
2   57.5    0.0
3   40.0    1.0
4   50.0    0.0
5   57.5    3.0
6   70.0    1.0
7   80.0    1.0
8   90.0    0.0
9  100.0    1.0
```

Keep in mind that empty string is different than NaN, latter might be created using python's `None`.